# TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

I am trying to update the props data sent to a component on a button click to a single component in `vue`.

Button click triggers an action loads the data from a config. But this throws the error and the error message was not clear. Find the error here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgTJ7.jpg

If I pass the data directly without the button actions, it works fine.

My Main component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <MyList v-if="listItems" :elements="listItems"/>
    <button @click="showSlider">Show Slider</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// imports the components and config files

export default {
  name: "ListView",
  data() {
    return {
      listItems: []
    };
  },
  components: {
    MyList
  },
  methods: {
    showSlider: function() {
         this.listItems.push(configs['elements'])
    },
</script>
```

**NOTE: If i provide the data to `listItems` by default it works**

And `MyList` file

```js
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="each in elements" :key="each.id">
      {{each.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
<template>

<script>
// imports the components and config files

export default {
  name: "MyList",
  props: {
    elements: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this usually happens to me when i'm not declaring my components or have a typo in the declarations. i suggest you install a `linter` on your IDE to check everything out for you.

Comment: where is the button click function that you're referencing?

Comment: @MojoAllmighty I already have a linter installed. That was the first thing I checked and found no such issues

Comment: @maembe

Missed that sorry. updated the code. Plese check it

Comment: When you call `listItems(configs['elements'])` shouldn't you use `this.listItems(configs['elements'])` ?

Comment: @LuccasParoni Hi luccas, I was using the same, corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, in general. But in my case, the issue is with `push` in the following function.

```
 showSlider: function() {
     this.listItems.push(configs['elements'])
},
```

Storing the same from `Vuex` and using dispatcher to update the same works like a charm. And I use computed property to load the state from the `vueX` and pass it to **MyList**